# Boolean Function Tightening

Tags: vba, excel

I have a boolean function that checks to see if a Worksheet Name exists tied to a checkbox. While I have coding that stops the checkbox from errors while it is true, if it false, the boolean value gives me an error 13.

```
Function WorksheetExists(sheetName As String) As Boolean
    WorksheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & sheetName & "'!A1)")
End Function
```

What I want to do, is set it so that if there is no value in the sheetName, the function simply ends. Is this possible?

Comment: `sheetExists = Not IsError(Evaluate("Sheet1!A1"))`

Comment: I am confused. How should I implement this code with the current code?

Comment: `Function WorksheetExists(sheetName$) As Boolean: WorksheetExists = Not IsError(Evaluate(sheetName & "!A1")): End Function`

Answer (score 2):

You can test for a value being passed as an argument. The below sets the function to False (the default value) if the length of the string passed as sheetName is 0 characters

```
Function WorksheetExists(sheetName As String) As Boolean

    If Len(sheetName) = 0 Then Exit Function
    WorksheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & sheetName & "'!A1)")

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in performance, this runs about 30x faster

```
Function WorksheetExists(sheetName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo EH
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)
    WorksheetExists = True
Exit Function
EH:
    WorksheetExists = False
End Function
```